# opendaylight dynamic backup restore

Tags: backup, apache-karaf, opendaylight

We are currently using nitrogen version of Opendaylight. Our requirement is to restore the binary backup from MDSAL without restart of ODL/Karaf server.

Could you please advise some approaches to achieve this??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By binary backup I assume you're referring to the online backup functionality. Online restore is not supported/implemented. IMO, there's not much point to even try to implement that since you'd likely end up essentially restarting all components/apps anyway to ensure the new state is properly synchronized/converged throughout the system. Hence you might as well just restart the karaf process.

That said, if you have a strong requirement for online restore, we always welcome contributions. You also might want to look at the daexim project: https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Daexim:Main.